# Show the evolution of map over time in Beamer

Tags: beamer, timeline

Hi Tex StackExchange forum users, I want to show the evolution of map over time in Beamer. (The map pics are of the same size.) I also want to insert a timeline at the bottom of the slide to indicate the year. I've attached pictures to show what I want to accomplish. Can anybody help? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

I refer to this thread and modify the code a little bit, but somehow still can't produce what I want because it shows the same figure. [Evolution bar with dates in a Beamer presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438424/evolution-bar-with-dates-in-a-beamer-presentation)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
 \tikzset{
    highlight on/.style={alt={#1{fill=red!80!black,color=red!80!black}{fill=gray!30!white,color=gray!30!white}}},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Timeline}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5]%[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
% \draw[line width=2mm,-latex,red!20] (-0.2,0) -- (9,0);
\draw[line width=1mm,-latex,red!20] (-0.2,0) -- (20+0.2,0);
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using int(\X-2000),count=\Z] in {2000,2010,2019}
{
\draw[highlight on=<\Z>] ({\Y-0.2},-0.5) -- ({\Y+0.2},-0.5) -- (\Y,-0.1) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=south,highlight on=<\Z>,fill=white,rotate=45,anchor=south
west,inner sep=0pt] at (\Y,0.2) {\X};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{figure}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Figure1.png}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Figure2.png}}
\only<3>{\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Figure3.png}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code for beamer we can play with. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Shouldn't it be sufficient to show one slide after the other, just using a different image for each?

Comment: Hi, I refer to this thread (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438424/evolution-bar-with-dates-in-a-beamer-presentation) and modify the code a little bit, but somehow I can't produce what I wanted. Ingmar's suggestion is doable. I can do that!

Comment: Hi, Just try to use slide one by one and on each slide put Your image and it should work as a slow .gif

Comment: Your code currently produces 3 slides (with some horizontal jumping in the images). That seems to be correct in terms of what you want, no?