# Latex table: Zoom in

Tags: tables, beamer, zooming

I have generated a slide with tables. I'd like to highlight some aspects.
Is there a possibility to highlight 3 elements and to do something similar to what is done here?

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438218/beamer-uncover-magnification-using-tikz-spy-library/438238#438238
```

You'll find the code below.
I'd like to zoom in for: The row with 'Scale C', 'Quantity D' and 'Table Entry B'

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Characteristics of atmospheric motion}
        \tiny
        \begin{table}
            \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
            \begin{+array}{colspec={Q[wd=0.568\linewidth]},delimiter={right=\rbrace,left=.}}
                \caption{}
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                    Table entry A&a\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry B&b\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry C&c\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry D&d\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry E&e\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \begin{+array}{colspec={@{} l}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=\rbrace}}
                    {Table entry E1)\\
                    Table entry E2}
                    \end{+array}
                    &\triangle e\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry F&f=\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry G&g\sim\qty{10}{km}\\ 
                \end{tblr}\\[-1ex]
                    \caption{}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Quantity A&a\sim\qty{10}{kg}\\
                        Quantity B&b=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity C&c=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity D&d=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity E&e=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr}   
%                \end{+array}
            \end{+array}
                \qquad
                \begin{minipage}{0.34\linewidth}
                    \caption{}
                    \vspace{-1ex}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Scale A&L\textsubscript{a}=\frac{a}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale B&L\textsubscript{b}=\frac{b}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale C&L\textsubscript{c}=\frac{c}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale D&L\textsubscript{d}\frac{d}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale E&h\textsubscript{e}=\frac{e}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr} 
                \end{minipage}              
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\framezoom` to zoom in on certain parts of your slide (remove `[border=1]` to hide the rectangles on the first slide):

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{}
    \begin{frame}
        \tiny
        \begin{table}
            \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
            \begin{+array}{colspec={Q[wd=0.568\linewidth]},delimiter={right=\rbrace,left=.}}
                \caption{}
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                    Table entry A&a\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry B&b\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry C&c\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry D&d\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry E&e\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \begin{+array}{colspec={@{} l}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=\rbrace}}
                    {Table entry E1)\\
                    Table entry E2}
                    \end{+array}
                    &f\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry F&f=\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry G&g\sim\qty{10}{km}\\ 
                \end{tblr}\\[-1ex]
                    \caption{}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Quantity A&a\sim\qty{10}{kg}\\
                        Quantity B&b=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity C&c=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity D&d=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity E&e=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr}  
%                \end{+array}
            \end{+array}
                \qquad
                \begin{minipage}{0.34\linewidth}
                    \caption{}
                    \vspace{-1ex}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Scale A&L\textsubscript{a}=\frac{a}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale B&L\textsubscript{b}=\frac{b}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale C&L\textsubscript{c}=\frac{c}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale D&L\textsubscript{d}\frac{d}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Scale E&h\textsubscript{e}=\frac{e}{X}\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr} 
                \end{minipage}              
        \end{table}
        \framezoom<1><2>[border=1](9cm,3.8cm)(2cm,0.5cm)
        \framezoom<1><3>[border=1](0cm,5.5cm)(2cm,0.5cm)
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed a while to find the error! Works well!!